# Why doesn't "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalSorters" extension point get invoked?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have been developing an Eclipse plugin(with tycho) which sorts the java code completion predictions. But the extension point "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalSorters" doesn't get invoked when running the project as Eclipse Application under Eclipe IDE.

I've created a class that extends "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.AbstractProposalSorter" and implemented the sorting logic. When I build the project(using tycho maven build) and install it in an Eclipse IDE it works fine. But if I try to run the project from Eclipse Ide as Eclipse Application the custom Sorter doesn't get invoked.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalSorters">
        <proposalSorter
                id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.RelevanceSorter"
                name="by sca relevance"
                class="org.code.completion.MyCompletionsSorter"/>
</extension>
```

Comment: Look at the 'Run > Run Configurations...' dialog and find your RCP in the Eclipse Applications section. Check that the plugin is actually being included in the run.

Comment: It's been included in the configuration. @greg-449

Comment: Changing the proposal id to something other than id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.RelevanceSorter" adds the new sort proposal. But how to make it the default one?

Comment: You can't override an existing extension just by using the same id - which one gets used will be random. For a RCP you can set the default in the plug_customization.ini